# GM task manager

Tags: gm-preparation, tools

Is there a system or application that will help a GM keep stuff more organized? I am look for something that I can download to my computer or phone that can web my stuff together and add new things the PC's do. I cannot find one, and I am not even sure if one exists. I can keep my stuff on paper, but a task manager/organizer would be really helpful to have too. Anyone know of such a application or system?

Comment: I'm not sure this can be answered well. What is it specifically that you need? A way to keep track of things you want to happen (timeline-esque), a notepad (such as Notepad for Android), something to hold character data, or something else?

Comment: yeah that and like a fold type thing. I wasn't sure if there was a common thing that did all that. Such as keep up with characters, changes within the kingdom etc. A notepad timeline-esque would be good, but I was more looking for a system/application in place if there was one